# Jasmine Test- Need to manually set values to be expected

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, mocha.js

For testing with Angular.js, Mocha, and Jasmine I have this test for `DeviceVal` value file:

```
describe("load balancer device: value", function() {
  var DeviceVal;
  DeviceVal = null;
  beforeEach(function() {
    return module("main.loadbalancer");
  });
  beforeEach(inject(function(_DeviceVal_) {
    return DeviceVal = _DeviceVal_;
  }));
  return it("should default the id to 'device not loaded'", function() {
    return expect(DeviceVal).toEqual({
      readonly: false,
      lb: "device not loaded"
    });
  });
});
```

For one of my other tests, I have this which uses the `DeviceVal` value file:

```
describe("load balancer controller: readonly", function() {
  $scope = DeviceVal = LoadBalancerSvc = SearchSvc = $state = $sce = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('main');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$state_, _LoadBalancerSvc_, _DeviceVal_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $state = _$state_;
    LoadBalancerSvc = _LoadBalancerSvc_;
    DeviceVal = _DeviceVal_;

    $controller('HeaderCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    //to resolve all the promises we have on the mocked service
    $scope.$digest();
    lb = { ha_status: "secondary", id: "34584"};
    this.lb = lb;
    spyOn(LoadBalancerSvc, "searchDevice").and.returnValue(
      {get: function() {
          return { then: function(fn) { fn(lb)} }}});
    spyOn($state, "go");
  }));

  it('scope data memembers to have their stuff', function() {
    $scope.searchButton.submit();
    expect(lb).toEqual(this.lb);
    expect(lb['ha_status']).toEqual("secondary");
    expect(DeviceVal.readonly).toBe(true);
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith("main.loadbalancer.vips", {id: this.lb.id});
    });
});
```

The issue I am having is I want to manually set the values in the second test of `DeviceVal` to custom values. But instead, the test expects the values to be the values in the first `DeviceVal` test file. It complains of:

```
Expected { readonly : true, lb : { ha_status : 'secondary', id : '34584' } } to equal { readonly : false, lb : 'device not loaded' }.
```

How can I make the second test where I can manually set the values `DeviceVal.lb = { ha_status: "secondary", id: "34584"};` and have `expect(lb['ha_status']).toEqual("secondary");` and `expect(DeviceVal.readonly).toBe(true);`?

---

**UPDATE**:

Here it is with mock DeviceVal, but I still get `Error: Expected { readonly : true, lb : { ha_status : 'secondary', id : '34584' } } to equal { readonly : fals
e, lb : 'device not loaded' }.`:

```
describe("load balancer controller: readonly", function() {
  $scope = DeviceVal = LoadBalancerSvc = SearchSvc = $state = $sce = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('main');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$state_, _LoadBalancerSvc_, _DeviceVal_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $state = _$state_;
    LoadBalancerSvc = _LoadBalancerSvc_;
    DeviceVal = _DeviceVal_;

    $controller('HeaderCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    //to resolve all the promises we have on the mocked service
    $scope.$digest();

    //MY ATTEMPT AT MOCKING THIS DATA
    DeviceVal.lb = { ha_status: "secondary", id: "34584"};
    DeviceVal.readonly = true;

    spyOn(LoadBalancerSvc, "searchDevice").and.returnValue(
      {get: function() {
          return { then: function(fn) { fn(DeviceVal.lb)} }}});
    spyOn($state, "go");
  }));

  it('scope data memembers to have their stuff', function() {
    $scope.searchButton.submit();
    expect(DeviceVal.lb).toEqual({ha_status: "secondary", id: "34584"});
    expect(DeviceVal.lb['ha_status']).toEqual("secondary");
    expect(DeviceVal.readonly).toBe(true);
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith("main.loadbalancer.vips", {id: DeviceVal.lb.id});
    });
});
```

Comment: You would need to mock `DeviceVal`

Comment: @PSL I attempted to mock the DeviceVal data, but still same result. I updated the bottom of the post with my code

Comment: Do you by any chance have a plunker

Comment: No, I wouldn't know how to post all this data plunker. But, I updated the bottom of the post with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. From http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-controllers/,  I created the mock data like this:

```
describe("load balancer controller: readonly", function() {
  $scope = DeviceVal = LoadBalancerSvc = SearchSvc = $state = $sce = null;

  beforeEach(function() {

    eviceVal = {}
    module('main', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('DeviceVal', eviceVal);
    });

    inject(function() {
      eviceVal.lb = { ha_status: "secondary", id: "34584"};
      eviceVal.readonly = true;
    });
  });
```